# How to append data to already existing hive backend file?

Tags: file, hive, append, backend

I'm writing a shell script where I need to append data to the existing hive table. I have my data in edge node and later moving it to HDFS. But it not letting me append the data to the hive.

`hadoop fs -rm /user/hive/warehouse/db/report/daily_report.txt`
`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /../logs/${process_NM}_${start_ts}_final.txt /user/hive/warehouse/db/report/daily_report.txt`

I tried to run the script by removing `hadoop fs -rm /user/hive/warehouse/db/report/daily_report.txt` this line, I thought if I don't remove this file it will append the data. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Each Hive table and partition has location in HDFS where the data is being stored. To append data into Hive table all you need is just to put new file into table location.

Instead of overwriting file just put the new file into the same location. For example like this (suppose every day you have new file with timestamp in the name):

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /../logs/${process_NM}_${start_ts}_final.txt /user/hive/warehouse/db/report/${process_NM}_${start_ts}_report.txt
```

Or you can do without specifying target file name and your file will be copied into location:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /../logs/${process_NM}_${start_ts}_final.txt /user/hive/warehouse/db/report/
```

Also consider partitioning your table by date and loading new partitions using [LOAD DATA command](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=82903069#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables).